Urgent help with LWE Estimator
I am trying to estimate LWE parameters. I know of the GitHub library for LWE estimator but it has no instructions for installation and also provides no guidance for running simple examples. I have been trying to use the jypyter notebook linked on the GitHub page, but it runs out of time pretty quickly to my disappointment. Any detailed help will be immensely appreciated.

There is in a fact a documentation here, but it might be a bit tricky to navigate around it if you are not used to it.
For a basic example, we first need to have sage installed, as well as the lattice estimator cloned from its GitHub repo. Then in your terminal cd to the cloned lattice-estimator directory and launch sage with the sage command.
Start by importing the module in sage:
from estimator import *

A very simple and fast estimation for Kyber512 can be performed using the following code:
LWE.estimate.rough(schemes.Kyber512)

If we need to be more precise, we need to calculate the real estimates and not the rough ones, using:
LWE.estimate(schemes.Kyber512)

If custom parameters are needed, let's say for some classical BFV encryption, it is also possible. We need to choose a scheme (LWE in this case), and parameters for the scheme, namely $n$ the ring dimension, $q$ the ciphertext modulus, $\chi_s$ the distribution for the secret key and $\chi_e$ the distribution for the error.
params = LWE.Parameters(n=2^14, q=2^438, Xs = ND.Uniform(-1,1,n), Xe=ND.DiscreteGaussian(3.19))

After defining those parameters, it is straightforward to (roughly) estimate the security by running the same code as with Kyber:
LWE.estimate.rough(params)

Note that estimation can take a lot of time (hours...).

Thanks a ton! I could execute it now. I had a query though. How do you determine the value of q here for CKKS? I am trying to use openFHE library and was trying to run estimator for this example here https://openfhe.discourse.group/t/openfhe-ckks-chooses-modulus-chain-that-doesnt-guarantee-128-bits-of-security/405 If you see the modulus table, it shows the number of log_q bits to be 40. So does that mean I need to feed 2^40 as value of q in the lattice estimator? Also how big can this q be? Any idea how it is related to the security parameter? I am confused between parameters q and Q

I made a typo that is now corrected. See in the new version I set $q$ to $2^{438}$ for $\log_2(q) = 438$, so yes in your case you can directly put 2^40.
Usually $q$ (ciphertext modulus) is chosen automatically by your library, or by following the standard https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/939
